# assemblyscript - how to get keys/values of public variables

Tags: webassembly, assemblyscript

I have the following:

```js
class Here {
  public id: string = "here"
  public dao: string = "good"

 good(): void {

 }
}
```

In the `good` function, I need to write a code that returns the keys and values of public variables of `Here`. Since this is assemblyscript, It's really hard. I don't want to repeat `id` and `dao` in `good` since this is easy example. In the real world, I got 20 public variables and repeating them 2 times is horrible.

Any idea ? I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: Welll, there is nothing to clarify. If you understand assemblyscript, you would understand what I am asking. I dont care about private vars. And inside good, all I need is to get all public keys

Comment: There seems to be work[1] better reflection, which would lead to `Object.keys()`.
The only options I see are: 1. Your own `visitor-as` transform with custom compilation code for `Here` (hard) 2. Serialize using `json-as` and parse the json string for the values you need (possibly easier than it seems) and 3. some use of `@operator("[]")` overloading (you may have to still repeat), depending on what you want to do.


[1] https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/292